# Unit test for copy function

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a c++ function called `copyMyFile(string src, string dest)`, which simply copies src file to destination. Now I need to write a unit test for this function. As I have never written a unit test I am not sure what should it include.

I mean in my `test_copyMyFiles()` unit test method shall I only make a call to `copyFiles()` method with some parameters and that's it? Or I should do some other staff in order for the unit test to be complete?

Comment: Situations to worry about: empty file names; the same file name twice; invalid file names. Things to check: the copy of the file is identical to the original; what happens when there isn't enough disk space for the copy; error reporting; what happens if the destination is a directory instead of a file name.  Just random thoughts off the top of my head.

Comment: thanks for the answer. let me ask one more thing. In order to call copyMyFile, I first need to have some file, so I guess in test_copyMyFiles() method I need to create a file first. If I have also a function createMyFile(), can I use it in my unit test? or it is not good idea to use one user defined module while unit testing another user defined module?

Comment: Roughly, if you've already unit-tested the file creating code, it should be OK to use it while testing your file copying code (assuming it passed).  What would be less good is unit testing the file copying code and finding that there's actually a bug in the file creating code — that would lead to confusion.  So, by all means write unit tests that use trusted (tested) code, but don't use untrusted (untested) code.  That does mean you have to build a dependency list, and you can't afford cycles in the dependency list.

Comment: thank you Jonathan for you quick help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to answer since they seem to have been of some use.*</sup>

Situations to worry about include: empty file names; the same file name twice; invalid file names. Things to check: the copy of the file is identical to the original; what happens when there isn't enough disk space for the copy; error reporting; what happens if the destination is a directory instead of a file name.

> In order to call `copyMyFile`, I first need to have some file, so I guess in `test_copyMyFiles()` method I need to create a file first. If I have also a function `createMyFile()`, can I use it in my unit test? Or it is not good idea to use one user defined module while unit testing another user defined module?

Roughly, if you've already unit-tested the file creating code, it should be OK to use it while testing your file copying code (assuming it passed). What would be less good is unit testing the file copying code and finding that there's actually a bug in the file creating code — that would lead to confusion. So, by all means write unit tests that use trusted (tested) code, but don't use untrusted (untested) code. That does mean you have to build a dependency list, and you can't afford cycles in the dependency list.